# Git repository icon

Tags: macos, git, bitbucket, git-tower

Is there an accepted path and/or filename scheme for Git repository icons?

I noticed that two of the apps I use most frequently ([Tower for Mac](http://www.git-tower.com/) and [Bitbucket.org](http://bitbucket.org/)) have entirely different ways of specifying repository icons: Bitbucket.org requires adding it via the site's UI, while tower asks to add an `icon.png` file in the repo root.

Assuming that Git doesn't already support specifying an icon path (assumption based on `man git-config`), is anyone aware of a more "standardised" way to monkey-patch repo icons in Git? By more "standardised" I mean something along the lines of the way people use `.gitkeep` to commit empty directories whose content shouldn't be committed.

Comment: `icon.png` seems to be quite common. SourceTree supports it, too.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of.

If you store the icon in your repo, that won't make a git gui aware of it, unless it is programmed to look for it. Git itself has no special knowledge about that file.

[GitHub](https://github.com), for instance, has no special way to illustrate a repo.